# libopencv2.3-dev conflict

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I enabled the ROS Electric repository in Ubuntu 11.10. However, while installing ros-electric-desktop-full, I ran into the following dependency conflict - ros-electric-vision-opencv depends on libopencv2.3-dev version 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-7~oneiric; however, the version of libopencv2.3-dev available is 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~oneiric. I think the ros-electric-vision-opencv dependency list needs to be updated to bring it in sync with the version of libopencv2.3-dev.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11921/libopencv2.3-dev-conflict/) by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2011-11-13

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS Electric repository has been updated and the conflict has been resolved.

---

Originally posted by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) with karma: 287 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try again, the repositories now appear in sync again and I did not experience any conflicts (switch to packages.ros.org if you're using a mirror, as they may not be completely updated yet).

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ros-electric-desktop-full is already the newest version.
```

Package details:

```
apt-cache show libopencv2.3 libopencv2.3-dev 
Package: libopencv2.3
Source: libopencv
Version: 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~natty
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Ethan Rublee <erublee@willowgarage.com>
Installed-Size: 8508
Homepage: http://opencv.willowgarage.com
Priority: extra
Section: libs
Filename: pool/main/libo/libopencv/libopencv2.3_2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~natty_amd64.deb
Size: 3521640
SHA256: 6ecee345593f5cdca55aafc36fa99db1e440d2960f8a02a887b6ce78e9fa1f78
SHA1: 368bf1cef7a5f2aefa296f21c8e77fb9461c304f
MD5sum: 4b3e884785f26583d2e5dd8b1cb7b2e3
Description: OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision)
    OpenCV is released under a BSD license, it is free for both academic and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python and soon Java
    interfaces running on Windows, Linux, Android and Mac. The library has >2500 optimized algorithms (see figure below). It is
    used around the world, has >2.5M downloads and >40K people in the user group. Uses range from interactive art,
    to mine inspection, stitching maps on the web on through advanced robotics.

Package: libopencv2.3-dev
Source: libopencv
Version: 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~natty
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: Ethan Rublee <erublee@willowgarage.com>
Installed-Size: 3144
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libopencv2.3 (= 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~natty), libpython2.7 (>= 2.7), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), libopencv2.3-bin (= 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~natty), pkg-config, cmake (>= 2.8), python-numpy, python-support, libavcodec-dev, libswscale-dev, libgtk2.0-dev, libjasper-dev, libjpeg62-dev, libpng12-dev, libtiff4-dev, zlib1g-dev, libavformat-dev, liblapack-dev, libv4l-dev
Conflicts: libcv-dev, libcvaux-dev, libhighgui-dev
Replaces: libcv-dev, libcvaux-dev, libhighgui-dev
Homepage: http://opencv.willowgarage.com
Priority: extra
Section: libdevel
Filename: pool/main/libo/libopencv/libopencv2.3-dev_2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~natty_amd64.deb
Size: 729462
SHA256: 421086c421551d4e8e2164a5b4d2bb24bb05c54d4e39850900b5fad0f7ac8748
SHA1: 821e3a2aa0960a2f89c92b456abd12b68bd9e6ad
MD5sum: 972cf599dbfc3aecd457c96144744dd9
Description: OpenCV (Open Source Computer Vision)
    OpenCV is released under a BSD license, it is free for both academic and commercial use. It has C++, C, Python and soon Java
    interfaces running on Windows, Linux, Android and Mac. The library has >2500 optimized algorithms (see figure below). It is
    used around the world, has >2.5M downloads and >40K people in the user group. Uses range from interactive art,
    to mine inspection, stitching maps on the web on through advanced robotics.
```

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on 2011-11-16**:
I hope it is resolved soon.

**Comment by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on 2011-11-15**:
when will the problem be resolved?

**Comment by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on 2011-11-15**:
Here is the bug report: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5247

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2011-11-14**:
@Aditya, would you please post a link to the bug report? - Thanks!

**Comment by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on 2011-11-14**:
Reported as a bug (for Ubuntu 11.10, x86).

**Comment by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on 2011-11-14**:
I have the same problem here I have just upgrade to ubuntu 11.10, please report it as a bug

**Comment by [Aditya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1106/aditya/) on 2011-11-14**:
I just tried and still have the same conflict. It is probably a good idea to report it as a bug.

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-13**:
Indeed, looks like everything is up to date except the oneiric-32bit version: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-electric-vision-opencv/

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2011-11-13**:
I still have the same problem here, libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-8~oneiric is installed and ros-electric-vision-opencv shows libopencv2.3-dev (= 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-7~oneiric) as dependency.